# Run SQL queries against shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Is there any way I can import a shapefile into QGIS, then run spatial SQL queries against it?

I can obviously use `ogr2ogr -sql` to do this, but I have to import the output into QGIS each time to look at it, which is a pain.

It would be great if I could just import the shapefile into QGIS, then run SQL against it and see the results instantly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a virtual layer. Load your Shapefile in QGIS, then go to `Layer / Add Layer / Add-Edit Virtual Layer`. Type the SQL you want.

For instance, if your shapefile is named `myshp` and has attribute `test` you can query as:

```
select * from myshp a
where a.test = 1234;
```

Or you can make a spatial query using the `geometry` field:

```
select * from myshp 
where st_intersects(geometry, make_point(1,2));
```

Comment: amazing, thanks for this!