# Use SQL on Layer in QGIS/SQL console in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql

There is the `Field Calculator` which has a lot of functionalities. Then there is `Select by Expression` which has a SQL Style Syntax.
However, is it possible to write plain SQL in QGIS on a Layer like a shapefile or geopackage?

Comment: yes, via a [virtual layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268997/run-sql-queries-against-shapefile-in-qgis/269019#269019)

Answer (score 0):

No, the tool `Select by Expression` is not using proper SQL. It's QGIS Expression. https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html

It has its own syntax.
But it works for any layer provider : ogr, geopackage, postgresql, csv as long as you have loaded the layer in QGIS.

Comment: I know that, that is why I am asking if there is a specific tool that uses SQL :)

Comment: Well, your question is not really clear. Can you copy paste exactly your query as an example ? Virtual layer might be ok ? Layer properties -> Source -> Query builder is SQL dialect on shapefile etc, but for filtering. What is the final goal, select, extract, filter ?